# Any way if we can remove repeated values in a single cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column like Department ID:
it has Values like:

-

1. 11\22\34\34
2. 33\33\44\44
3. 22\22
4. 11\11\22

So I want the repeated values removed and the output should be like:

1. 11\22\34
2. 33\44
3. 22
4. 11\22

Please let me know how to do it or where to look? Thanks

Comment: this question should be able to answer it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127581/removing-duplicate-values...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127581/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-string-in-visual-basic)

Comment: @DaBeau96 The best answer in that question includes a function which does exactly what the OP wants, so I am voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @YowE3K sounds good